# Error al utilizar model_utils Django Python

Tags: python, django

buenas tardes. Me encuentro desarrollando un sistema en Django, sin embargo, al momento de utilizar model_utils, me marca un error, "No se ha podido resolver la importacion "model_utils.models"".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya lo instale desde la terminal "pip install django-utils", pero no puedo eliminar el error, ya trate de instalar versiones previas, e incluso cambiar la version del interprete, pero el problema persiste, espero me puedan ayudar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]